# Why does wget work and curl fail with a specific REST URL?

Tags: curl, wget

In answering [a question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/21932/298) on another site, I came across a strange discrepancy between `curl` and `wget` when trying to fetch from this URL: https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta

For some reason, `curl` just silently fails to download, while `wget` correctly fetches the file `A2Z669.fasta`:

```
$ ls -la
total 300
drwxr-xr-x   2 terdon terdon 266240 Dec 11 12:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 202 terdon terdon  32768 Dec 10 17:31 ..

$ curl https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta
$ ls -la
total 300
drwxr-xr-x   2 terdon terdon 266240 Dec 11 12:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 202 terdon terdon  32768 Dec 10 17:31 ..
```

Explicitly setting an output file doesn't help, that just creates an empty file:

```
$ curl -o file "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

$ ls -la
total 300
drwxr-xr-x   2 terdon terdon 266240 Dec 11 12:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 202 terdon terdon  32768 Dec 10 17:31 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon      0 Dec 11 12:25 file
$ cat file
$
```

And yet, `wget` works just fine:

```
$ wget https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta
--2023-12-11 12:24:42--  https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving www.uniprot.org (www.uniprot.org)... 193.62.193.81
Connecting to www.uniprot.org (www.uniprot.org)|193.62.193.81|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta [following]
--2023-12-11 12:24:42--  https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta
Resolving rest.uniprot.org (rest.uniprot.org)... 193.62.193.81
Connecting to rest.uniprot.org (rest.uniprot.org)|193.62.193.81|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/A2Z669.fasta [following]
--2023-12-11 12:24:43--  https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/A2Z669.fasta
Reusing existing connection to rest.uniprot.org:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘A2Z669.fasta’

A2Z669.fasta            [ <=>               ]     314  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-12-11 12:24:43 (6.65 MB/s) - ‘A2Z669.fasta’ saved [314]

$ ls -la
total 304
drwxr-xr-x   2 terdon terdon 266240 Dec 11 12:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 202 terdon terdon  32768 Dec 10 17:31 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon    314 Dec 11 12:24 A2Z669.fasta
```

It doesn't seem to be specific to that particular file either. I tried another URL from the same REST API (https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P05067.fasta) and got the same behavior.

I am running this on an Arch system with:

```
$ wget --version | head -n1
GNU Wget 1.21.4 built on linux-gnu.

$ curl --version | head -n1
curl 8.4.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/8.4.0 OpenSSL/3.1.4 zlib/1.3 brotli/1.1.0 zstd/1.5.5 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.4) libssh2/1.11.0 nghttp2/1.58.0
```

What's going on here? What would make `wget` work when `curl` fails?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://askubuntu.com/q/1036484

Comment: I always use `curl -vv` to "debug" issues with some url/http call. You should see the redirect if you add that option.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`wget` follows redirections by default, `curl` doesn’t. If you add `-L`, `curl` works fine:

```
curl -OL https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta
```

(`-O` tells `curl` to output to a file instead of standard output, matching `wget`’s default behaviour.)

Comment: Ah! Of course! I'm an idiot: that redirects to https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/A2Z669.fasta and that one I can get with curl.

Comment: Not an idiot ;-). `curl`’s handling of redirections is easy to forget.

Comment: In my mind, I have classified `wget` as a "command line browser" and `curl` as a "shell API to HTTP". I find, thinking about it this way helps me to understand why certain defaults are chosen. E.g. the default of `wget` to download to a file whose name matches the URI vs. `curl` streaming to stdout.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I tend to think along similar lines — `wget` as a command-line download tool (with its handy “mirror” features), and `curl` as a command-line HTTP tool.

Comment: Easy to forget because it's an annoying default. It would make far more sense to require an option to stop at a redirect.

Comment: @Barmar: I concur. Developpers should strive to follow the Principle of Least Astonishment (or of Least Surprise): (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) . But it is not always easy to get it right.

Comment: @OlivierDulac Of course, developers aren't always good at putting themselves into the users' perspective. And even once they get feedback they may not want to make an incompatible change.

Comment: @Barmar Curl is not a file downloader with some extra features, it's a tool for working with URLs of all sorts.  One of its fundamental design principles is to perform the most minimal actions possible unless specifically told otherwise by the user. If you want to change the default behavior of curl, you're more than welcome to edit your .curlrc file and add the --location directive there. This is why curl provides both the --location and the --no-location parameters, so everyone can use it as they prefer.

Comment: @OlivierDulac If you want to see some astonishment, change the curl default. There will be quite a bit of astonishment and some choice curse words. There's no reason to break existing functionality for millions of users when there's a trivial way to personalize its behavior.